# Any correlation between tempdb and sysmail?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any correlation between [tempdb] getting full and subsequently  db_mail disabled ? [This needs sysmail_start_sp to be executed in msdb]

Comment: Is this correct: You are stating that Database Mail has been disabled, but you are still having to cope with a ful TEMPDB?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is correlation between tempdb and db_mail.

Ref:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345368(v=sql.105).aspx

Database mail user service broker which in turn use tempdb.

> Service Broker helps developers build asynchronous, loosely coupled
> applications in which independent components work together to
> accomplish a task. These application components exchange messages that
> contain the information that is required to complete the task. Service
> Broker explicitly uses tempdb for preserving existing dialog context
> that cannot stay in memory. The size is approximately 1 KB per dialog.
> Also, Service Broker implicitly uses tempdb by the caching of objects
> in the context of query execution, such as work tables that are used
> for timer events and background delivered conversations.
>
> Database
> Mail, Event Notifications, and Query Notifications implicitly use
> Service Broker.

Comment: AWESOME; excellent SqlWorldWise

Comment: @Prashant if my answer satisfied your question please accept it. That way other users know that you are still not looking for an answer. Also others can be benefited by seeing an accepted answer.